# Group my elements in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create code to group every element of a column in another one by giving them a name. For instance:

```
Year:    colour:
2015     blue
2014     red
2003     yellow
2011     blue
2006     red
```

If the year is `2015` or `2011` the given colour has to be "blue", if the year is `2014` or `2006` the colour has to be "red".

Comment: I suggest to start with a loop in the second column... while not catching any doubles... later on you can build a table while every header is unique (red, blue...)

Comment: Yes I definitely go for it, I do not code in vba so I probably can refine a code but create a brand new will be tough, how can I start ?

Comment: `For Each...` with the given range. And for each item (except the first) check the target array for it...

Comment: Simply start by dim variables... use the ms-help for all the functions you need... its no real magic... Start easy by just debug.print every item... then try it without doubles... and always keep in mind: `debug.print` is your best friend at all times :D

Comment: At the very fist you need to know will it just be a calculation (function) or a subroutine (sub)... right now a sub would be better to start with... `Sub MyFirstSub()` will do for now... An `End Sub` should automatically pop up...

Comment: Cuz it doesnt do anything right now we simply add a `debug.print "hello"` and execute it... when executing, a "hello" pops up in the direct command window...

Answer (score 0):

Assume that nothing more will happen, I just write a solution:

```
Sub test()
  Dim c As Range, i As Long
  Set c = Cells(1, 4)
  For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    Do
      If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
        c.Value = Cells(i, 2).Value: c.Offset(1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value: Exit Do
      ElseIf c.Value = Cells(i, 2).Value Then
        Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1, c.Column).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value: Exit Do
      Else
        Set c = c.Offset(, 1)
      End If
    Loop Until Len(c.Offset(, -1).Value) = 0
    Set c = Cells(1, 4)
  Next
End Sub
```

Since this answer has been adjusted to only solve this question, it needs to be adjusted for anything that differs...